# Blob's DataUri vs Base64 string DataUri

Tags: javascript, base64, blob, data-uri, fileapi

As you know & [stated in w3](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#url) it is possible to create a url for a Blob object in javascript by using Blob's createObjectUrl. On the other hand, if we have a data as a Base64 encoded string we can [present it as a Url](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397) with the format "data[MIMEType];base64,[data>]".

Let's suppose that I have a base64 encoded string that was generated from an image that is very popular on these days :) "The red dot" image in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#HTML).

```js
var reddotB64 = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg";
```

I'm 100% sure that if I create a URL conforming the Data URI Scheme as stated above, then, I'll be able to put a link element and download it from the browser: please see the code example below:

```js
var reddotB64 = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg";
var reddotLink = document.createElement("a");
reddotLink.target = "_blank";
reddotLink.href = "data:image/png;base64," + reddotB64;
document.body.appendChild(reddotLink);
reddotLink.click();
document.body.removeChild(reddotLink);
```

This works prettywell and displays the image in a new tab. On the other hand I'll try to create the link by using Blob as follow:

```js
var reddotB64 = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg";
var reddotBlob = new Blob([atob(reddotB64)], { type: 'image/png' });
var reddotLink = document.createElement("a");
reddotLink.target = "_blank";
reddotLink.href = URL.createObjectURL(reddotBlob);
document.body.appendChild(reddotLink);
reddotLink.click();
document.body.removeChild(reddotLink);
```

This code is decoding base64 encoded string variable `reddotB64` via [`atob`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#dom-btoa) function. And then, creating a Blob object and continues with [`URL.createObjectURL`](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-createObjectURL) function. In that case, since I've decoded `reddotB64` from base64 to binary and created a Blob of type image/png and then create object url from that I expect it to work but it's not working.

Do you have a clue why it's not working? Or am I missing anything on the standards? Or doing something wrong in Javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16245768/1266820) is the answer. Looks like it is an encoding issue. In order to convert/decode Base64 string to binary(UInt8Array/byte) using `atob` is not enough. After using `atob` it is required to use UTF-16 character code: and we achieve this by using `charCodeAt` function for every character in the decoded string. As a result we get UTF-16 encoded binary string which is definately working. Just create a `Blob` and then call `URL.createObjectURL`.